# Subtle differences in C pointer addresses

Tags: c, pointers, bit

What is the difference between:

```
*((uint32_t*)(p) + 4);
*(uint32_t*)(p+4);
```

or is there even a difference in the value?

My intuition is that in the later example the value starts at the 4th index of the array that p is pointing at and takes the first 4 bytes starting from index 4.  While in the first example it takes one byte every 4 indices. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: What array is `p` pointing to?

Comment: We kind of guessed `p` is a pointer. A pointer to what type? That's the most important aspect of it when it comes to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. p points to a hex array.

Answer (score 2):

The `p+4` expression computes the address by adding `4*sizeof(*p)` bytes to the value of `p`. If the size of `*p` is the same as that of `uint32_t`, there is no difference between the results of these two expressions.

Given that

> `p` is an `int` pointer

and assuming that `int` on your system is 32-bit, your two expressions produce the same result.

Comment: p points to an array of hex value, will that make a difference?

Comment: @user2251001 Only the type of `p` matters, the values (hex, octal, decimal) does not matter.

Comment: @user2251001 You are welcome! If the answer works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.